# bam() returns negative deviance explained values

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I'm trying to run GAMs to analyze some temperature data. I have remote cameras and external temperature loggers, and I'm trying to model the difference in the temperatures recorded by them (camera temperature - logger temperature). Most of the time, the cameras are recording higher temperatures, but sometimes, the logger returns the higher temperature, in which case the difference ends up being a negative value. The direction of the difference is something that I care about, so I do have to have non-positive values as a response. My explanatory variables are percent canopy cover (quantitative), direct and diffuse radiation (quant.), and camera direction (ordered factor) as fixed effects as well as the camera/logger pair (factor) for a random effect.

I had mostly been using the `gam()` function in `mgcv` to run my models. I'm using a scat distribution since my data is heavy-tailed. My model code is as follows:

`gam(f1, family = scat(link = "identity"), data = d)`

I wanted to try using `bam()` since I have 60,000 data points (one temperature observation per hour of the day for several months). The `gam()` models run fine, though they take a while to run. But the exact same model formulas run in `bam()` end up returning negative deviance explained values. I also get 50+ warning messages that all say:

`In y - mu : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Running `gam.check()` on the fitted models returns identical residuals plots. The parametric coefficients, smooth terms, and R-squared values are also almost identical. The only things that have really noticeably changed are the deviance explained values, and they've changed to something completely nonsensical (the deviance explained values for the `bam()` models range from -61% to -101% deviance explained).

I'll admit that I'm brand new to using GAM's. I know just enough to know that the residuals plots are more important than the deviance explained values, and the residuals plots look good (way better than they did with a Gaussian distribution, at least). More than anything, I'm curious about what's going on within the `bam()` function specifically that's causing the function to pass that warning and return a negative deviance explained value. Is there some extra argument that I can set in `bam()` or some further manipulations I can do to my data to prevent this from happening, or can I ignore it and move forward since my residuals plots look good and the outputs are mostly the same?

Thanks in advance for any help.